# register custom config namespace for Symfony MicroKernel

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, configuration, microkernel

I have an app with a MicroKernel and would like to use Symfony's TreeBuilder with a custom config because the app will be quite generic and I would like to have as much as possible configured externally. My problem is, I can't get my custom `namespace` registered for symfony:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "research" 
(in /var/www/html/src/app/config/config.yml). Looked for 
namespace "research", found "framework", "twig", 
"sensio_framework_extra", "web_profiler"
```

I have this `Configuration` class:

```
<?php
namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode    = $treeBuilder->root('research');

        // @formatter:off
        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('questions')
                    ->children()
                        ->integerNode('client_id')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('client_secret')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()// twitter
            ->end();
        // @formatter:on

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

and my `AppExtension`:

```
<?php
namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ConfigurableExtension;

class AppExtension extends ConfigurableExtension
{
    // note that this method is called loadInternal and not load
    protected function loadInternal(array $mergedConfig, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        dump($mergedConfig);
    }

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'research';
    }
}
```

In my `AppKernel` class, I'm initializing the extension like this and as a result **I also get an output from the `dump($mergedConfig)` call in my `AppExtension`** from my *original* `research.yml`

```
<?php
namespace App;

use App\DependencyInjection\AppExtension;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$loader = require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// auto-load annotations
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

/**
 * Class AppKernel
 */
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    ...

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $c, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $researchConfig = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/config/research.yml'));
        $appExtension = new AppExtension();
        $appExtension->load(researchConfig, $c);

        $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/config/config.yml');
    }

    ...
}
```

nevertheless, when my `config.yml` looks like this, I get the error mentioned above:

```
framework:
    secret: S0ME_SUPER_SECRET
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }


research:
    questions:
       client_id: 2342323423
       clent_secret: mysecret
```

so what do I need to do, to actually register my namespace *research* so I can properly overwrite it? Or does it *have* to an external vendor bundle?

Comment: Have not tried what you are doing but I'm pretty sure you will need to make a bundle.  All it should take is one bundle class.

Comment: yes until sf 3.3 it has to be a bundle, otherwise it won't be recognized. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you dont register a bundle and so symfony doesnt know the bundle config namespace.

I cant say how you could fix this with your approach but i would suggest to make a AppBundle instead of the App and register AppBundle in `public function registerBundles()`.

See f.E. in some boilerplates like https://github.com/ikoene/symfony-micro.

Alternativly you could try to set up your project with the new symfony Flex.
This already uses MicroKernel, is bundleless and also supports latest stable symfony version (sf3.3).
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html#using-symfony-flex-in-new-applications

So no need to build something off the track yourself.

Comment: you're right, built as a bundle it works like expected in a "normal" symfony app. but I haven't tried flex though..

Comment: Bit off topic but even in flex you would still need a bundle to handle your research configuration.  The app itself will no longer need to be organized as a bundle, but there will still be bundles for managing plug in stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Since Symfony does not recommend the usage of Bundles anymore (), to create a Bundle is *NOT* the way to solve this.

@see [https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html][1]

> In Symfony versions prior to 4.0, it was recommended to organize your own application code using bundles. This is no longer recommended and bundles should only be used to share code and features between multiple applications.

[1]: Symfony Bundle Documentation